# Is the pointwise limit of monotonically increasing functions a uniform limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

For a real-valued sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ on the closed interval $[0,1]$, each $f_n$ is monotonocally increasing and suppose that the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to the function $f$ by $n\xrightarrow{}{}\infty$ at each point

1. Show that the inequality holds\begin{align*}\sup_{z\in[x,y]}|f_n(z)-f(z)|\leq \max\{|f_n(x)-f(y)|,|f_n(y)-f(x)|\}\end{align*}
2. Show that, when the function $f$ is continuous, the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$

I know that a sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ is bounded on some interval that is convergent uniformly to $f$ on that interval iff $||f_n-f||\xrightarrow{}{}0$. But this will not help to solve this problem, how do we get this inequality? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What are $x$ and $y$ on the right side?

Comment: Sorry I mistyped $z\in[x,y]$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Could you give me an idea to proceed I am really stuck with this

Comment: $f_n(z)-f(z) \leq f_n(y)-f(x)$ and $f(z)-f_n(z) \leq f(y)-f_n(x)$ since $f_n,f$ are increasing.

Comment: For 2., you can use a compactness argument after showing (using 1. and the continuity of $f$) that for all $x$ and all $\varepsilon$ there are $\delta>0$ and $N$ such that $|f_n(z)-f(z)|<\varepsilon$ for all $z\in[0,1]\cap]x-\delta,x+\delta[$ and all $n\geq N$.

Comment: @Helmut How do we use 1? I could not prove 1 yet

Comment: For 1, you can use the hint by @KaviRamaMurthy and think about what $a\le b\le c$ means for $|b|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(z)-f(z) \leq f_n(y)-f(x)$ because $f_n(z) \leq f_n(y)$ (by monotonicity) and $f(z) \geq f(x)$ (so $-f(z) \leq -f(x)$). Similarly you get $f(z)-f_n(z) \leq f(y)-f_n(x)$. From these you conclude that  $f_n(z)-f(z) \leq \max \{|f_n(y)-f(x)|,|f(y)-f_n(x)|\} $ and $f(z)-f_n(z) \leq \max \{f_n(y)-f(x),f(y)-f_n(x)\} $. If $a \leq b$ and $-a \leq c$ then $|a| \leq c$ so we now have $|f(z)-f_n(z)| \leq \max \{|f_n(y)-f(x)|,|f(y)-f_n(x)|\} $. Taking sup over all $ z\in [x,y]$ we get the inequality in the first part.

Let $\epsilon >0$ and use uniform continuity of $f$ to choose $\delta >0$ such that $|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenver $|x-y| \leq \delta$.  Divide $[0,1]$ into subintervals $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$ with $x_{i+1}-x_i <\delta$ for each $i$.  Apply the inequality in the first part to each of the intervals $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$. Choose $n_1, n_2$ such that $n \geq n_1$ implies $|f_n(x_i)-f(x_i)|<\epsilon$ for $n \geq n_1$ and $n \geq n_2$ implies $|f_n(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i+1})|<\epsilon$ for $n \geq n_1$. Now you see that $\sup_{x_i \leq z \leq  x_{i+1}} |f_n(z)-f(z)|<2\epsilon$ and this is true for all $i$. Hence $\sup_{0\leq z \leq  1} |f_n(z)-f(z)|<2\epsilon$ finishing the proof.

Comment: Sorry for bothering, here it is not given $f$ is uniformly continuous

Comment: @Priya In 2) it is given that $f$ is continuous. Any continuous function on $[0,1]$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Don`t we need to prove that

Comment: That is a very basic result. It is proved as a thorem in Calculus books as well as any book that discusses compact metric spaces. I don't think you are required to prove that here. It is Theorem 4.19 in Rudin's Principles.  @Priya

Comment: The Heine–Cantor theorem asserts that every continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

Comment: How do we conclude that $\sup_{x_i\leq z\leq x_{i+1}}|f_n(z)-f(z)|<2\epsilon$ from the previous two sentences

Comment: How to apply inequality in the first part

Comment: @Priya I am epalcing $x$ by $x_i$ and $y$ by $x_{i+1}$  and using triangle inequality: $|f_n(x_{i+1})-f(x_i)| \leq |f_n(x_{i+1})-f(x_{i+1})|+|f(x_{i+1}-f(x_i)|<\epsilon+\epsilon$.

Comment: Here, do we need to prove first the limit function $f$ is also a non-decreasing function?

Comment: @Priya Yes, and that is proved by just taking limit on both sides of $f_n(x)\leq f_n(y)$ where  $x<y$.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear. After taking the limit of both side, how can we say the inequality still hold?